# A backwards relationship

Tags: code-golf, string

Write a program or function that, given two ASCII strings `A` and `B`, will produce strings `A'` and `B'` where the common substrings are reversed in their place. The process for finding `A'` is as follows:

1. `A'` is initially empty.
2. If the first character of `A` is in `B`, find the longest prefix of `A` which is a substring of `B`. Remove this prefix from `A` and add its reversal to `A'`.
3. Otherwise, remove this first character from `A` and add it to `A'`.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 until `A` is empty.

Finding `B'` is done similarly.

### Example

Let's consider the strings `A = "abc bab"` and `B = "abdabc"`. For `A'`, this is what happens:

- `A = "abc bab"`: The first character `"a"` is in B and the longest prefix of A found in B is `"abc"`. We remove this prefix from A and add its reversal `"cba"` to A'.
- `A = " bab"`: The first character `" "` is not in B, so we remove this character from A and add it to A'.
- `A = "bab"`: The first character `"b"` is in B and the longest prefix of A found in B is `"b"`. We remove this prefix from A and add its reversal (which is still `"b"`) to A'.
- `A = "ab"`: The first character `"a"` is in B and the longest prefix of A found in B is `"ab"`. We remove this prefix from A and add its reversal `"ba"` to A'.
- `A = ""`: A is empty, so we stop.

Thus we get `A' = "cba" + " " + "b" + "ba" = "cba bba"`. For B', the process is similar:

```
B = "abdabc"  ->  "a" in A, remove prefix "ab"
B = "dabc"    ->  "d" not in A, remove "d"
B = "abc"     ->  "a" in A, remove prefix "abc"
```

Thus we get `B' = "ba" + "d" + "cba" = "badcba"`.

Finally, we return the two strings, i.e.

```
(A', B') = ("cba bba", "badcba")
```

### Test cases

```
"abc bab", "abdabc" -> "cba bba", "badcba"
"abcde", "abcd bcde" -> "dcbae", "dcba edcb"
"hello test", "test banana" -> "hello tset", "tset banana"
"birds flying high", "whistling high nerds" -> "bisdr flyhgih gni", "wihstlhgih gni nesdr"
```

---

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Do we presume all input is lowercase ASCII? Is the exact output expected to be akin to `"cba bba", "badcba"` including quotes and comma?

Comment: @TimmyD The exact input/output format is your choice. You may not presume the input is lowercase ASCII - it could be any printable ASCII.

Comment: Is the empty string a legal input?

Comment: @MtnViewMark Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth, 29 bytes

```
M&G+_Je|f}TH._GhGg.-GJHgzQgQz
```

[Test Harness.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=M%26G%2B_Je%7Cf%7DTH._GhGg.-GJHgzQgQz&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=abc+bab%0A%22abdabc%22%0Aabcde%0A%22abcd+bcde%22%0Ahello+test%0A%22test+banana%22%0Abirds+flying+high%0A%22whistling+high+nerds%22&debug=0&input_size=2)

Input format is:

```
abc bab
"abdabc"
```

Output is:

```
cba bba
badcba
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>120</s> 111 bytes

```
import Data.List
a&b=(a#b,b#a)
[]#_=[]
(a:y)#b=[a]%y where p%(i:w)|reverse(i:p)`isInfixOf`b=(i:p)%w;p%x=p++x#b
```

Test runs:

```
λ: "abc bab"&"abdabc"
("cba bba","badcba")

λ: "abcde"&"abcd bcde"
("dcbae","dcba edcb")

λ: "hello test"&"test banana"
("hello tset","tset banana")

λ: "birds flying high"&"whistling high nerds"
("bisdr flyhgih gni","wihstlhgih gni nesdr")
```

Answer (score 1):

## SWI-Prolog, 312 bytes

```
a(A,B,X,Y):-b(A,B,"",X),b(B,A,"",Y).
b(A,B,R,Z):-A="",R=Z;sub_string(A,0,1,_,C),(sub_string(B,_,1,_,C),(string_length(A,J),I is J-1,between(0,I,K),L is J-K,sub_string(A,0,L,_,S),sub_string(B,_,L,_,S),string_codes(S,E),reverse(E,F),string_codes(Y,F));S=C,Y=C),string_concat(S,V,A),string_concat(R,Y,X),b(V,B,X,Z).
```

Example: `a("birds flying high","whistling high nerds",X,Y).` outputs

```
X = "bisdr flyhgih gni",
Y = "wihstlhgih gni nesdr" .
```

A way, *way* too long solution that goes too show how verbose Prolog is when dealing with strings. It might be possible to shorten this thing using codes arrays (`` `birds flying high` ``) instead of strings (`"birds flying high"`).

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7, <del>169</del> <del>156</del> <del>152</del> 141 Bytes

```python
m=lambda A,B:(b(A,B),b(B,A))
def b(A,B,C=''):
 while A:j=next((j for j in range(len(A),0,-1)if A[:j]in B),1);C+=A[:j][::-1];A=A[j:]
 return C
```

The function `m` takes the 2 strings as input.It calls the `b` function twice which does the actual processing according to the specs.
[Demo here](https://ideone.com/cODLdh).
Testing it -

```
l=[("abc bab", "abdabc"),
("abcde", "abcd bcde"),
("hello test", "test banana"),
("birds flying high", "whistling high nerds")]
for e in l:
    print m(*e)
```

OUTPUTS:

```
('cba bba', 'badcba')
('dcbae', 'dcba edcb')
('hello tset', 'tset banana')
('bisdr flyhgih gni', 'wihstlhgih gni nesdr')
```

PS: Thanks to orlp for the solution using `next()`

Comment: `m=lambda A,B:(b(A,B),b(B,A))`

Comment: Also you can replace `while len(A)>0` with just `while A`. Similarly `if len(p)>0` becomes `if p`.

Comment: `if len(p)` can also be `if p`. (Already said above, but you missed it.)

Comment: @mbomb007 Didn't read it properly. Just replaced `len(p)>0` to `len(p)`. Thanks for that :)

Comment: Even shorter: `while A:j=next((j for j in range(len(A),0,-1)if A[:j]in B),1);C+=A[:j][::-1];A=A[j:]`.

Comment: @orlp Nice. Didn't know about much about generator expressions and `next()` function. Thanks for that :)